# Hyperref mysteriously enabled or who loaded hyperref

Tags: packages, hyperref

I can't figure out where do I load the `hyperref` package. I know it sounds odd, but I scanned all my preamble and couldn't find a single `\usepackage{hyperref}`. I feel really stupid, but I don't know where to look for it. Is it possible that some other package I load loaded `hyperref` on it own? Any ideas are welcomed. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Yes another package can load hyperref. Look in the log-file. It records the loaded packages.

Comment: without a minimal no-one will be able to assist you. Many other packages look for it and if it is not loaded they will input it automatically.

Comment: Beamer loads hyperref.

Comment: @Yiannis: I value the importance of ME, but in this case I don't it is really hard to generate one, as it is involved. I'll try to add something.

Comment: the point is that the process of creating the MWE will almost certainly solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the log file and you'll notice that included files are printed within parentheses. And if a file that you include includes another file, that file will appear within parentheses within the first parentheses.  So each parenthetical group delimits a file.

```
(./a.tex
 % tex is now processing a.tex ...
 (./b.tex % a.tex requests b.tex be read
  % tex is now reading b.tex
  ) % tex is now done with b.tex and is reading
  % the rest of a.tex
 ) % done with a.tex
```

So search the log file for `hyperref.sty`.  Find the parenthetical group that includes it, and the file at the beginning of that group is your culprit.

Comment: OH! So that's what the parentheses are for. They make sense now...

Comment: Yes seems like the problem was in my personalized .sty file which was not updated. I guess I don't know how to use it... I reverted to self contained preamble :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\listfiles` in your document and then have a look into your log file. It shows the loading of all packages at the beginning and the end of the log file.

If this doesn't help, then copy your document source, delete all text and then uncomment the preamble line by line from the bottom to top, until `hyperref`isn't loaded anymore.

Some document classes, like beamer and powerdot, load hyperref by default. And with `PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{hyperref}` you can disable all settings.

Comment: Thnx! This looks good. I'll try it.

Comment: I'm using a personal `.sty` file where I load most of the things. It lives in my home part of the latex directories. Is it possible, that I changed the file, but it was not really changed? I have to do something like `texhash` to it whenever I edit it?

Comment: @dror you shouldn't have to `texhash` if it's in your personal `texmf` directory...

Comment: @Dror: texhash is only needed for TEXMF and TEXMFLOCAL. TEXMFHOME is searched recursively by TeX. With `kpsewhich <file>` you can easily controll which file is used by TeX.